# Why do "Sell Something" posts from a private group not contain a message field?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The results I get from the Facebook Graph API (all supported versions) on a private FB group differs from what I see when I go to the actual Facebook website.  "Sell Something" posts from the private Group's /feed don't contain information such as the "message" property for some reason, even though I can see it on the website.

From Facebook.com:

> Christine : Can't go anymore! Selling last minute
>   Front Orchestra tickets to the ...
>
> Ingrid : For Sale: Portable booster seat high chair $20 — Pick up
>   at ...

From the Graph API:

```
[{
      ...
      "message": "Can't go anymore! Selling last minute Front Orchestra tickets to the ...", 

     "privacy": {
        "value": "", 
        "description": "", 
        "friends": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "created_time": "2015-04-19T00:07:11+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2015-04-19T04:44:49+0000", 
      "is_hidden": false, 
      ...

    }, 
    {
      "privacy": {
        "value": "", 
        "description": "", 
        "friends": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "created_time": "2015-04-16T22:11:36+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2015-04-19T04:41:01+0000", 
      "is_hidden": false, 
      ...
    }]
```

You will notice that there is only a "message" field in the first post, and not in the second -- although, I don't see any reason that this should be happening.

Comment: It is a for sale post. They are special and the API don't handle them currently

Comment: You are right!  only "Sell Something" posts aren't showing properly -- I wonder if support for that is coming soon?

Comment: Nothing is announced so I wouldn't hold my breath

Comment: I updated the question to specify that it's only for Sell Something posts

Comment: Any updates on how to properly make "sell Something" posts?  I would love to get this figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an **attachments** attribute in **fields** path parameter. The URL will look like this:

```
/{group-id}/feed?fields=attachments
```

Then you'll have an object of type **group_sell_product_item** in the **attachments** array inside of each applicable post object. You can also have the post's photos.

I still wonder how to get the price info...

Comment: any idea how to geht the price info?